# Java. Nested classes with static member. How can we circumvent it?

Tags: java, static, nested

My question is: it's known that *nested class cannot have a static member* (only if the class isn't described as **static**). But sometimes we need to have it.

Ex: we have a **library**. It has **books** *(we will consider books as the inseparable part of library, I just can't guess about another example)*.
In class **Library** I should describe nested private class **Book**. *Nested because Book exists only in a Library*(as I described before). Private because we want to permit creation book outside of the Library. I want to have counter of all books, stored in all libraries. I simple situation I should have static counter, but there I can't. And I can't describe Book as static class because Book belongs to the Library.

Comment: If your book has to belong to a single library, what is the point of keeping a counter of this book stored in all libraries? The ones stored in other libraries are different instances, they cannot be shared, so your counter can be an instance field

Comment: @Matthew Farwell: it's a count of all books in all libraries, not a count of this book in all libraries.

Comment: Then it's stored in the library, it makes more sense to have the librar store the number of books which it has, and this can be a static field for the total if necessary, or you could have a method which totals all of the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a counter of all books in all libraries, I would rather ask each library for its count of books, and total the lot.

I think this is much better handled by asking the libraries for info about what they contain. The libraries look after their books, and the responsibility lies with them. Maintaining that shared state outside the libraries breaks encapsulations (and depending on the implementation, may introduce you to pain when concurrently updating etc., if you choose to do that in the future).

Remember that one of the points of OO is to *tell objects to do things for you*.

I'm not sure about your assertion re. books existing only in a library. They *belong* to a library, but that's slightly different. Your books can be standalone objects (not necessarily inner classes), and perhaps your libraries should contain a book factory, that creates a book with a reference to the owning library. Check out the [Factory pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning for having a nested class doesn't really make sense.

If you really want Book to only be accessible by library, you can declare it package private by putting it in a package with library and declaring the class to be private.

That way, only library can use the class.

e.g.

```
package com.company.library;

private class Book {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you can't have a static member in `Book` is that a `Book` is a non-static member of `Library`. As such, the `Book` class has an implicit reference an enclosing class instance (an instance of `Library`). You have a number of options:

1. Make the `Book` class static.
2. Keep the static counter in the Library class instead.
3. Make `Book` a completely separate class from `Library` altogether. A library instance can keep a counter of how many books it holds.

I personally think #3 is the better option. A `Book` should not be forced to be in a library, it should also be allowed on a `CoffeeTable`. :P

Answer (score 0):

I can understand the problem that you mentioned but tell me something.The mapping of Library to book is One to many. That is one Library can have many books.So in my opinion this could be handled better if you have a Separate library class and separate books class. You can have an arrayList associated with Library class of type Book eg:

Class Library {  private ArrayList<.Books>; }

such kind of thing would help you to solve the problem in a better way. For keeping a count of the book have a count class that will be associated with each book instance same way as we have the Library to Books.

Answer (score 0):

Nested (non-static) classes in Java tend to be a generally confusing concept. I would recommend against using them, unless you really know what you are doing, and have a convincing need (since other people having to maintain your code will also have to understand it). Nested classes are a kind of dark corner of the language, which it is always possible to avoid.

In general, the use case for making a class nested, is when the class is only *used* by the outer class. For example, the `Library` may have a `CardCatalog`, which is internal to the Library, and which never interacts directly with users of the Library. Even then, it will often be less confusing, if you make the relationship between them be slightly more explicit, by making the `CardCatalog` a static inner class, and passing it a `Library` instance in its constructor. Besides everything else, it will be more testable.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
class Library {

    private static long allBooksInAllLibraries;

    private class Book {

        private Book() {
            // this should be synchronized if threads are involved
            allBooksInAllLibraries += 1;
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-static nested lasses are really meant for cases where there is only one instance of the nested class per instance of the outer class. This is clearly not the case in your example.

Therefore you should either convert `Book` to a static nested class, or pull it out and create a regular class (this is the better option). You can restrict the access to it, by making it protected or package private (by just defining it with `class Book`).